# How to show the drafting mail in explorer Outlook? C#

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am developing custom button, the button just like "Reply All". But only the sender of original mail will add into the "TO" column, all other will move to "CC".

My question is how to show the draft in explorer( call InlineResponse?) ?

I has add 2 buttons in ContextMenu and Ribbon, if using the ContextMenu button, "`explorer.CurrentFolder.CurrentView.Reset()`" can reselect the original mail to show the draft, but ribbon button can't.

Ribbon can reflash using "`explorer.CurrentView = explorer.CurrentFolder.CurrentView`", but it's very unstable, the view setting for outlook will reset default sometimes......

I also tried "`explorer.ClearSelection()`" & "`explorer.AddToSelection(OriginalMailItem)`" but also no effect.......

All methods need to delay 2-3 second and not work every time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to open an inline response or just select/open an item in the explorer window?

Comment: open inline response.
i want to replace the "Reply All" Function. but can't open the editor interface...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open an inline response programmatically using the OOM. You best option is to select an original item and click the button on the UI programmatically. Automation UI may help in that case.

If you just want to get the item selected in the explorer window you can use the  [Explorer.ClearSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.clearselection?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3312);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which cancels any selection in the active explorer. After the `ClearSelection` method is called, the `Count` property of the `Selection` object that the `Explorer.Selection` property returns is zero. Then, the `SelectionChange` event fires unless prior to calling of `ClearSelection`, the current view did not contain any items, the current folder was empty, or the `Count` property was already zero.

Then you can use the [Explorer.AddToSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.addtoselection?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm3309);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which adds the specified Microsoft Outlook item to the selection in the active explorer. To be selected, the item must be selectable in the current view of the active explorer. Use the `IsItemSelectableInView` method to determine whether the item can be selected in the view. The item does not have to be visible in the view.

Under the following conditions, Outlook returns an error when you call the `AddToSelection` method:

- The specified item is not in the current view of the active explorer.
- The specified item is being edited in the current view of the active explorer.
- The current view has been filtered, and the application of the filter removed the item from the view.
- The specified item has not been saved.
- The specified item represents a StorageItem.
- No current view exists for the active explorer.

If the item is not selected and is selectable in the current view, calling `AddToSelection` causes the `SelectionChange` event to fire.

Calling `AddToSelection` does not scroll the view to make the selected item visible in the view and does not expand or collapse groups in the view.

Comment: thanks for your response, i had been already try `ClearSelection` & `AddToSelection`, i can see the mail from selected change to unselected and reselect in debug mode, but the mail view interface has not any change.......